# windowless .wmv in firefox

Tags: firefox, video, transparent, wmv, windowless

Is there any way to make windowless .wmv videos on firefox. Does windows media player plugin support windowlessVideo mode in firefox and if it does please tell me which version should i use

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embeding your wmv in a Silverlight player, using a media element?